# how to use xmltable to read values from a clob?

Tags: oracle, clob, xmltable

I'm trying to get the values of the  attributes from table MVR_DTL in column VENDOR_XML. VENDOR_XML is of datatype clob and contains an xml that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MVRCHPINFF_1.0>
   <MVRRecLoop>
      <CLoop>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN GENERAL</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN ST</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
         <CRec>
            <C_MVRNumberAddr>ROMAN CITY, ROME 111111</C_MVRNumberAddr>
         </CRec>
      </CLoop>
 </MVRRecLoop>
</MVRCHPINFF_1.0>
```

I tried running

```
SELECT c.Address  
    from MVR_DTL M,  XMLTABLE('/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop/CLoop/CRec'
passing XMLTYPE(M.VENDOR_XML)
columns Address XMLTYPE PATH './C_MVRNumberAddr') c;
```

I'm expecting something like

`ROMAN GENERAL    ROMAN ST    ROMAN CITY, ROME 111111`

but i only get 'Statement has failed, however your database does not return any error information.'

Oracle version 12.2.0.1.0

Comment: [Your query works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c46c5b62fe548aff87d14cd24b86318a). What version of Oracle are you on? Are you sure you want the results as XMLType, not [as VARCHAR2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=40f462943b8d425de5f4061ec5d3b5d3)? Maybe your client/application just can't handle that data type?

Comment: yeah I ran something similar and it worked also.  please show the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.Address from MVR_DTL M,  
XMLTABLE(
    'string-join(/MVRCHPINFF_1.0/MVRRecLoop/CLoop/CRec/C_MVRNumberAddr, "  ")'
passing XMLTYPE(M.VENDOR_XML)
columns Address varchar2(200) PATH '.') c;
```